# Access the widget class from the List of Widgets

Tags: list, flutter, widget

I made a list of widgets and i want to access setter in the class `DayButton`, but when i try `days[index].` it doesn't show the setter methods, it treats the output as a general widget but not the `DayButton` widget

here is the code.

```
class DayButtonRow extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  DBRState createState() => DBRState();
}

class DBRState extends State<DayButtonRow>{

  currentDay(int i){
    setState(() {
      current = days.elementAt(i).key;
      //I want to access the setter here to change the color of the button
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    currentDay(3);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: days
      ),
    );
  }
}

Key current;
List<Widget> days = [
  DayButton("MON"),
  DayButton("TUE"),
  DayButton("WED"),
  DayButton("THU"),
  DayButton("FRI"),
  DayButton("SAT"),
  DayButton("SUN"),
];
```

is there a way to access the `DayButton` widget class from the list?

Comment: declare days as `List<DayButton>` instead of `List<Widget>`?

Comment: thank you soo much that was sooo silly..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, declare it as `List<DayButton>`:

```
List<DayButton> days = [
  DayButton("MON"),
  DayButton("TUE"),
  DayButton("WED"),
  DayButton("THU"),
  DayButton("FRI"),
  DayButton("SAT"),
  DayButton("SUN"),
];
```